# Adding a entire column data below the other column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, project, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe like this:

```
time a   b
0    10  20
1    11  21
```

Now i need a dataframe like this:

```
time a
0    10
1    11
0    20
1    21
```

Comment: `df.melt('time')` or specifically : `df.melt('time',value_name='a').drop("variable",1)`

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any other way using join, concat and merge?

Comment: What is the usecase - why not melt ?

Comment: Okay thank you :) I find it easy since i am trying it for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with `melt`:

```
df.melt('time', value_name='a').drop('variable', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   time   a
0     0  10
1     1  11
2     0  20
3     1  21
```

Or if you have columns other than `a,b` in your data:

```
df.melt('time', ['a','b'], value_name='a').drop('variable', axis=1)
```